# Как добавить sharedpreference во fragment. Есть готовый код, но не удается запихнуть во фрагмент

Tags: java, android, xml

Правда перепробовал много всего, но видимо чего-то не учел. Уже дофига статей прочитал и все без успешно. Вообщем мне надо добавить например edit и 2 кнопки(сохранить и получить), это я добавил в файл xml. Далее мне нужно прописать логику для этого, но я не пойму как и куда надо это вписать для фрагмента определенного. В чистом проекте android studio у меня edit и 2 кнопки добавлены в activity_main.xml а логика в MainActivity.java и все работает, но вот где это же код прописать для фрагмента не знаю.

В activity_main.xml этот код:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
    android:onClick="onClickGet"
    android:text="@string/get"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClickSave"
    android:text="@string/save"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextSave"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.835" />
```

Это код для MainActivity.java

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private SharedPreferences pref;
    private EditText editSave;
    private final String save_key = "save_key";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        init();
    }
    public void onClickSave(View view) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
        edit.putString(save_key, editSave.getText().toString());
        edit.apply();
    }
    public void onClickGet(View view) {
        editSave.setText(pref.getString(save_key, "пусто"));
    }
    private void init(){
        pref = getSharedPreferences("Test", MODE_PRIVATE);
        editSave = findViewById(R.id.editTextSave);
        editSave.setText(pref.getString(save_key, "пусто"));
    }
}
```

В моем проекте используются fragment_doppokypki.xml это как activity_main.xml и в папке (java > com.example.название > ui > doppokypki ) есть 2 файла DoppokypkiFragment.java и DoppokypkiViewModel.java

В файле DoppokypkiFragment.java

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.example.reings30.R;

public class DoppokypkiFragment extends Fragment {
    private DoppokypkiViewModel doppokypkiViewModel;
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        doppokypkiViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(DoppokypkiViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_texpodderjka, container, false);
        final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_texpodderjka);
        doppokypkiViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);}});
        return root;}}
```

А в файле DoppokypkiViewModel.java такой код

```
package com.example.reings30.ui.doppokypki;
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;

public class DoppokypkiViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<String> mText;
    public DoppokypkiViewModel() {
        mText = new MutableLiveData<>();
        mText.setValue("Тут будет текст фрагмента");}
    public LiveData<String> getText() {
        return mText;}
}
```

Comment: Зачем тебе SharedPreferences? Сохранять текст из поля ввода? Это поле часть активити? А потом сохраненные данные передать во фрагмент? А почему поле ввода не часть фрагмента? Далее, SharedPreferences ты можешь спокойно вызывать и использовать в фрагменте. И еще, я не вижу тут привязки фрагмента к активити, это так надо? Потому что он тут висит, как не пришей ничего ничему.

Comment: Зачем тебе SharedPreferences? Нужен для настроек, то есть например выключить звук или уведомления и тд, чтобы после выхода оставались такими же, а при первом запуске дефолдно были настройки включены. 
Я вообще недавно начал пользоваться studio, думал это как раз и относится к фрагменту, что указано выше. А что тогда подвязано к этому фрагменту, например если создать проект в studio с navigation drawers, там будут фрагменты, где тогда для каждого фрагмента будет привязка эта к активити?

Answer (score 0):

Получение SharedPreferences в активити и фрагменте не отличаются, кроме одного момента.
В активити вы получаете экземпляр SharedPreferences таким образом:

```
pref = getSharedPreferences("Test", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

А во фрагменте подобное делается так:

```
pref = requireActivity().getSharedPreferences("Test", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Если все еще есть вопросы куда вставить код, то:
Код, который я привел выше - в onViewCreated()
Код, срабатывающий при нажатии кнопок - либо создаете свои listeners для них, либо можно на сам фрагмент повесить слушатель, код для всех кнопок можно будет вставить в onClick и останется лишь к каждой кнопке прикрепить listener методом setOnClickListener().

P.S. Если мой ответ не помог, то конкретизируйте, что именно не смогли вставить во фрагмент.

Answer (score 0):

В общем создаешь активити в котором размещен фрагмент, разметка такая(активити)

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".RegisterActivity" />
```

Здесь расположен только контейнер для фрагмента. Хотя можно и не только.

Далее в коде привязываешь фрагмент

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register_activity);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, RegisterFragment.newInstance())
                .commitNow();
    }
}
```

где "RegisterFragment.newInstance()" - это

```
 public static RegisterFragment newInstance() {
    return new RegisterFragment();
}
```

Это все делается автоматически студией при выборе соответствующего пункта (Activity+Fragment).

Теперь все. К активити пока не возвращаешься. В разметке фрагмента делаешь все как выше указал в активити. Там же в фрагменте и используй SharedPreferences.

И советую почитать про фрагменты. Там много интересного. Если хочешь менять фрагменты, то используй этот блок кода, с соответствующем фрагментом.

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, RegisterFragment.newInstance())
                .commitNow();
```

В студийном шаблоне NavigationDrivers  должен быть соответствующий контейнер для фрагментов типа этого "R.id.container". Вроде все.